# iPad universal app has method with 'not found in protocol' warning, but it works

Tags: ipad

My iPad universal app has a method I implemented from here:

[Best way to programmatically detect iPad/iPhone hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862140/best-way-to-programmatically-detect-ipad-iphone-hardware)

```
-(BOOL)isPad
{
  BOOL isPad;
  NSRange range = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] rangeOfString:@"iPad"];
  if(range.location==NSNotFound) isPad=NO;
  else isPad=YES;
  return isPad;
}
```

When I write my code like this:

```
if( [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] isPad] ) // do something
```

I get the warning:

'-isPad' not found in protocol

However, it's declared in my app delegate class:

```
-(BOOL)isPad;
```

And in the implementation (above).

Any ideas why this is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-delegate` returns an `id<UIApplicationDelegate>`. Even if *your app delegate* supports `-isPad`, the UIApplicationDelegate does not, which is the warning is about.

You need to cast the return value to your class to eliminate the warning.

```
YourAppDelClass* appDel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if ([appDel isPad]) {
   ...
```

Comment: Yes, that's how I solved it, by creating a ref variable.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Would I be able to cast it in a define statement in an h file?

Comment: Yes - #define kIsPad [(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] isPad]

Answer (score 0):

The compiler expects to find isPad  declared in the uiapplicationdelegate protocol.  Try making it an instance method of uiapplication instead.

Comment: I made a reference variable and used that to call the method and it removed the warning. Thanks

Comment: It would be simpler to call it the way I did it in the question, creating a ref variable every time is a pain.