# How to detect whether the host device is iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, device

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to programmatically detect iPad/iPhone hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862140/best-way-to-programmatically-detect-ipad-iphone-hardware)

I am preparing an app where in I want to use it on iPhone as well as iPad.

How to detect whether the current host device is iPhone or iPad?

Based on this I want to make changes to the User Interface

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479344/checking-if-users-device-is-ipad-or-iphone-ipod-difference-between-two-ways/23518735#23518735

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are so many ways to find in which device the App is running.

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
```

by using this code we can get current device version, so that we can check whether the device is iPhone of iPad.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    // iPad-specific interface here
}
else
{
    // iPhone and iPod touch interface here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the 'official' way to detect the device type at runtime:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
   // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
}
else
{
  // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```