# How to set different orientation to iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to programmatically detect iPad/iPhone hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862140/best-way-to-programmatically-detect-ipad-iphone-hardware)

For example I want my view to be portrait only on iPhone and landscape on iPad.

How to detect if I'm running on iphone or iPad in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write this in your `UIViewController`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I've seen this userInterfaceIdiom before. Just never thought it would be like this. Awesome, thanks